# 'A' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

I'm having a little trouble tracking a bug in the following piece of code. I've run it and it says "'A' : no appropriate default constructor available". Where exactly is a constructor without parameters being called?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int x;
public: A(int i) : x(i){}
        int get_x() const { return x; }
};

class B : public A
{
    int *y;
public: B(int i) :A(i){
    y = new int[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) y[j] = 1;
    }
        B(B&);
        int &operator[](int i) { return y[i]; }
};

B::B(B& a)
{
    y = new int[a.get_x()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.get_x(); i++) y[i] = a[i];
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, B a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.get_x(); i++)
        o << a[i];
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    B b(5);
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think you should know that? What compiler doesn't output line number of the error?

Comment: The answer is in your question. You have not defined a default constructor for `class A`. You need to add `A() {}` to the body of `class A`

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar That would be the wrong solution. Better to call `A`'s copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
B::B(B& a)
```

Is a constructor.  Since it is a constructor you need to construct the `A` part of `B` as `A` does not have a default constructor.  I believe you meant to make a copy constructor and if so that would be:

```
B::B(const B& a) : A(a)
{
    y = new int[a.get_x()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.get_x(); i++) y[i] = a[i];
}
```